# Изменение содержимого ячейки Google Sheets

Tags: google-spreadsheet, google-apps-script

Есть задача по изменению содержимого ячейки после заполнения (а именно - по удалению первого символа). Грубо говоря: ячейка автоматически заполняется некоторыми данными, в начале которых всегда один и тот же символ, и его нужно удалить.
Можно ли как-то такое реализовать через макросы?

Answer (score 0):

```
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
var range = sheet.getActiveRange();
var values = range.getValues();

for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
  var value = values[i][0];
  if (typeof value === 'string' && value.length > 0) {
    values[i][0] = value.substring(1);
  }
}

range.setValues(values);
}
```